# Identical link_to tags, one uses turbo the other doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo

I have 2 identical `link_to` tags, that produce indentical html, used in 2 different views. However one sends a turbo request, while the other doesn't (I believe). My goal is for both to use turbo to load a view. The one using turbo works as expected, however the other errors in the controller (`missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"]`).

Is there a reason one link would 'use turbo' (unsure if that's even the correct terminology) while the other would not?

The erb:

```
<%= link_to new_organization_funding_round_path(
  @organization, closed: true
  ),
  class: 'btn btn-white btn-xs',
  data: {
  method: 'get'
  } do %>
    <i class="ph-pencil-simple-line"></i>
  <% end %>
```

generating this html

```
<a class="btn btn-white btn-xs" data-method="get" href="/organizations/9l8yEx8Z/funding_rounds/new?closed=true">
  <i class="ph-pencil-simple-line"></i>
</a>
```

Evidence 1 uses turbo while other does not:
The link that 'works'/uses turbo does the following:

- When viewing the request in network tab, the initiator is listed as "turbo.es2017..."
- The program will execute the `binding.pry` in the `new.turbo_stream.erb`
- Request headers `Accept: text/vnd.turbo-stream.html, text/html, application/xhtml+xml`

The link that does not work:

- Errors with the missing template error above.
- Request headers `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9`
- Does not execute the binding.pry in `new.turbo_stream.erb`

Further details:
The views are rendered into HTML as such:

```
<div class="">
  <a data-method="get" class="btn btn-white btn-xs" href="/organizations/A1NAgG8X/funding_rounds/new?closed=true">
    <i class="ph-plus-circle-bold mr-0.5 text-sm"></i> Add closed funding round
  </a>      
</div>
<!-- BEGIN app/views/funding_rounds/_funding_round.html.erb -->
<div data-controller="collapsible" data-collapsible-show-value="false">
  <div data-collapsible-target="arrow">
    <div>
      <span>
        $0
      </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="btn btn-white btn-xs" data-method="get" href="/organizations/A1NAgG8X/funding_rounds/new?closed=true">
        <i class="ph-pencil-simple-line"></i>
      </a>        
.... [other irrelevant code]
```

As you can see, the tags are very close in the structure of elements on page. They are not in the *same* view however they are essentially adjacent. Also the inner text of the buttons is not the same, but I have reproduced this issue by copy/pasting the exact code blocks, so it's not relevant.

`new.turbo_stream.erb`:

```
<%
binding.pry
closed = params['closed']
%>
<%= render('organizations/organization_slideover', organization: @organization, active_tab: :funding_rounds) do %>
  <%= render 'funding_round_form', organization: @organization, funding_round: CompanyFundingRound.new, closed_round: closed %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried a slew of other modifications to the `link_to` tag trying to force it to use turbo. These included things like `turbo: true`, `turbo_stream: true` and variations within `data` as well. The only attribute that significantly changed anything was adding `format: :turbo_stream` to the path. This changed a few things:

- This activates the binding.pry in the `new.turbo_stream.erb`
- I receive an error in the view I try to render, `Missing partial shared/_slideover_content...`. `shared/_slideover_content.html.erb` is a file that rails is able to find using the link that works, but not here it seems. I imagine if this could be solved my issue may be solved using the `turbo_stream: true`.
- The request headers are still text/html. `Missing partial shared/_slideover_content` .

Comment: On a a side note you never need to do `method: 'get'` unless you're using a form. Thats what links do anyways... `data-method` also doesn't even work with Turbo which uses `data-turbo-method`.  https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#performing-visits-with-a-different-method